# $scope updates not reflected the view when it operated by not angular js Object

Tags: angularjs

I want to reflect $scope's data by emit $scope's method from another js file. But it can't.

My source is like this,.

### another.js

```
//o.delegate  refer HomeCtrl's  to $scope
// render Pagination by simplePagination 
o.delegate.renderOn(idx)
```

### home_controller.js

```
function HomeCtrl($scope,$routeParams,...){
  $scope.items = [];

  $scope.renderOn(idx){
      // fooo is called.
      console.log("called fooo");

      // changed $scope.items but $scope.items doesn't reflect view.
      $scope.items.append("foo");
  }
}
```

I want to operate $scope.items and reflect to my view. 
Do you have any idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to wrap the call to `append` in `$scope.$apply()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call the scope change from outside the angular handling loop. Therefore the update is not picked up automatically.

You can inform angular that you change the scope using the $apply function, which should fix your problem.
You should use a different function when calling from angular and from the external script, though.

```
function HomeCtrl($scope,$routeParams,...){
  $scope.items = [];

  //this can be called from within angular
  $scope.renderOn(idx){
      // fooo is called.
      console.log("called fooo");

      // changed $scope.items but $scope.items doesn't reflect view.
      $scope.items.append("foo");
  }
 //this is to be called externally
 var renderOnExternal = function(idx){
     $scope.$apply(function() {
         $scope.items.append("foo");
     });
    //or even: $scope.$apply(function(){ $scope.renderOn(idx);});
 }
}
```